# How to divide on column in two column in select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named `Voucher` with these columns:

```
V_id big int,
V_Date Date,
V_Type Char(2),
Amount money,
Nature Char(10),
V_No big int,
Ledger_Id var char(20),
```

Now I want to generate a report named columns,

```
V_Date, Ledger_Id, V_No, V_Type, Credit_Amount, Debit_Amount.
```

where the `Debit_Amount` and `Credit_Amount` will come from the same column named `Amount` depending on the condition if `nature = Credit` then amount will go into the `Credit_Amount` and in the Debit it will go 0 on the same row.

And the same for the another condition if `Nature = debit` then `Amount` will go into the `Debit_Amount` column and in this row `Credit_Amount` will be 0.

How can this be done in a single query? Or do I need multiple queries for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Case when` it will help you,

```
select 
  V_Date, 
  Ledger_Id, 
  V_No, 
  V_Type, 
  case when Nature = 'Credit' then Amount  else 0 end Credit_Amount, 
  case when Nature = 'Debit' then Amount  else 0 end Debit_Amount 
from voucher
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Praveen sir and Sankar Raj sir  thanks a lot it worked for me thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Trying this one

```
CASE 
   WHEN NATURE = 'CREDIT' 
      THEN AMOUNT 
      ELSE 0 END AS Credit_Amount, 
CASE 
   WHEN NATURE = 'DEBIT' 
      THEN AMOUNT 
      ELSE 0 END AS Debit_Amount
```

Comment: This is **not** valid T-SQL syntax - you're missing the single quotes around the values for the `Nature` column, and you're missing an `END` before the `AS` to signal the end of the `CASE` expression ....

Answer (score 0):

You can add two if conditions with alias for your columns:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    IF(Nature='Credit', amount, 0) AS Credit_Amount, 
    IF(Nature='debit', amount, 0) AS Debit_Amount 
FROM <table_name>;
```

Though I have tried this in MYSQL, but it is very much possible in any DBMS.

Comment: The question is about **Microsoft SQL Server** and this syntax does **not** work in SQL Server ....